# Performance comparison between IronRuby and IronPython

Tags: .net, performance, ironpython, ironruby

We're aiming to implement a scripting mechanism, using DLR's Microsoft.Scripting and hosting assembly.

Now, someone knows about any performance difference between IronRuby 1.0 and IronPython 2.6?

To my understanding they have different compilers, but IronPython seems more mature and tested, but if anyone has documentation or knowledge on this issue, that would be appreciated.

Comment: If performance matters then you should use neither.

Comment: Thanks for the ridiculous answer @nobugz.

Comment: @nobugz: performance always matters. Don't confuse it with performance-critical, that's very different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IronPython has had more time to focus on performance improvements, but IronRuby has made significant performance improvements as of late. However, we rarely pin IronRuby up against IronPython. While people may comment here that one or the other is faster, and certain special cases/examples may even be uses to *prove* this, there is no exhaustive comparison available today.

Comment: Okay thanks, sounds like something I should consider doing in my spare time. I suppose the difference should not actually be that big, since they are both sitting on top of DLR and CLR, which does some optimizations on the backend.